# getCanonicalHostName for localhost works on Win 7 but not XP?

Tags: java, windows, hostname

The following simple code works fine on Windows 7, returning a fully-qualified name (e.g. 'myhost.x.com'). However, when run on Windows XP machines in the same network, it returns only the hostname (e.g. 'myhost'). Is this a known issue? Any workarounds?

```
hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
```

Context: want to match up processes from the same originating machine on a remote server. The client processes pass in their hostname so that the server can group requests from the same client machine even when they are from different apps on that machine. We're seeing mismatches for apps running on client machines using XP when one client process is Java and the other is C# because one is fully-qualified and one is not. Windows 7 clients work fine. Initially thought it was .NET that was not obtaining the FQDN on XP, but now it appears to be Java clients using the code above.

Update: on same XP machine, a C++ client (not .NET) is also able to get the full-qualified name. So it seems that of the three, only java on this machine is unable to obtain the FQDN using this API. This is Java 1.6.0_20-b02. Also, the code in Java and C++ needs to work on non-windows platforms as well.

Comment: Maybe this is just a bug without a good workaround? We'll likely take a slightly different approach using the simple name (e.g. 'mymachine') rather than the qualified name.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the method - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName() - says

"Gets the fully qualified domain name for this IP address. Best effort method, meaning we may not be able to return the FQDN depending on the underlying system configuration."

I believe that Java asks the resolver in the operating system which apparently is different on 7 and XP.  Anyway this request can be nixed by the SecurityManager, meaning that you may have to reconsider your identification process. Perhaps even do the DNS-lookup yourself based on *all* the IP-numbers the machine has.

What is the information you need and why?

Comment: See the "Context" paragraph after the code on what we need and why: want to identify remote requests that originated from the same machine. Therefore need a unique to identify client machines. Hostname alone may not be unique so want fully-qualified name. Some clients are java, others .NET. C# methods work correctly on these same XP machines. Java code works correctly on Win7.

Comment: I read the context, but the match criteria might be because of something else.  Consider having your application request a log-token from the central server, where this request contain all the information available, and then the client use the log-token in their logs.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify: The client processes pass in their hostname so that the server can group requests from the same client machine even when they are from different apps on that machine.

Comment: Also there is a problem with multiple interfaces which all have an IP-number (very common with host virtualization software) - which one to choose?  Why can't you just use the IP-number?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, you've given us some things to consider. I think we've got a workaround that avoids using FQDN. However, the original issue remains: why does this java API that works fine on Win7 (and I think linux) not work on XP, on machines where C# and non-.NET C++ are able to obtain the FQDN? Seems like a bug in the getCanonicalHostName method.